# requests_html TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 9000 ms exceeded

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

I wanna scrape a dynamic website `https://www.woorank.com/en/www/webmatrices.com` (i.e. takes time to load - JAVASCRIPTED) using `requests_html`. When it tried the below code an error popped up.
Currently I am using it in my PC, but I'll be using it in my server.
I don't want any selenium recommendation because I don't have java installed in my server so that I could run it in my server.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
asession = HTMLSession()
headers = {
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
r = asession.get('https://www.woorank.com/en/www/webmatrices.com', headers = headers)

file = open('newsite.html', 'w+')
file.write(str(r.html.render(timeout=9)))
file.close()
```

This is the Error that popped:

```
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 512, in _async_render
    await page.goto(url, options={'timeout': int(timeout * 1000)})
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyppeteer\page.py", line 885, in goto
    raise error
pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 9000 ms exceeded.
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to augment the render timeout parameter to a higher value than 9. Try `r.html.render(30)`.